# Make part of the Visable Screen Scroll with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I make part of the Kivy screen able to move up and down with Scrolling and have a scroll bar? Also, are there multiple options for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [ScrollView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html)? You can scroll it by clicking and dragging (like on mobile) or with a mouse wheel. Otherwise, you can create a [Slider](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.slider.html?highlight=slider#module-kivy.uix.slider) and bind it together with the ScrollView to make it scroll.

Comment: I did but cannot find the method to make many scrolling parts of the screen. I want to define the box or the boundary of the screen parts that will move so not the whole screen scrolls at once.

Comment: Only the widgets inside a ScrollView scroll, anything outside stays the same. You can put many differenct ScrollViews in one screen. If you have a good widget hierarchy, there will be no problems.